# Displaying posts on website (phpBB)

Tags: php, phpbb

Okay so I'm a very beginner at making website and I only know hmtl and ccs coding so far. I got a website (interqueo.hu) and a phpBB forum. On my website I would like to have place on the right side where the visitors can see the latest 5 posts on the forum. I found a tutorial but as I said I'm a beginner and not familiar to php coding.

Link for the tutorial: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Practical.Displaying_posts_and_topics_on_external_pages

I did this so far but I don't know where to put the rest of the codes from the tutorial.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php
/*
* home.php 
* Description: example file for displaying latest posts and topics
* by battye (for phpBB.com MOD Team)
* September 29, 2009
*/

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/bbcode.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('viewforum');
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append example of your choice to the `home.php` file. As far as I understand, the fourth example do your job.

Optionnaly, the function could be append to a new function file (`function_XXXX.php`)in the `includes` directory.

Then you could included this new file with this code :

```
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_XXXX.' . $phpEx);
```

But I don't think this is really useful, only your script will call it. Thus, the function could remain at the beginning of your `home.php` file.

Answer (score -1):

As you are a beginner, I would recommend looking at the database you are going to be using first.  Use PHPMyAdmin, or other UI to check the data existing there, and create a dummy database to display your posts.  Take a note of your DB tables, and fields, and practice querying the data there first.  After it, you will understand better the calls made from PHP to MYSQL database.  I have never used phpBB, but I am sure you can read their documentation on how to manage the database.

Comment: Even if it is a good advice, you're not answering this question. Try to gain a minimum reputation so you will be able to post comments.